# Who will progress to the semi-final/final in case of equal points?

Tags: rules, cricket, tournaments

I run the stats for a cricket comp, and at the end of the season the point table looks like this:

```
TEAM    P   W   D   L   FIP BP  PTS
Ninjas  6   3   1   2   10  6   30
Charger 6   3   0   3   8   6   26
Hawks   6   3   2   1   4   6   26
Wolves  6   1   1   4   2   2   10
```

And because I store everything in a database running a query gives it to me automatically.

For the finals, top of the ladder (Ninjas) goes through to the final, and will play the winner of 2 v 3. The Chargers and Hawks are level on points. Head to head between Chargers and Hawks is 1 all. Should the Chargers be in second or the Hawks to get the home semi?

Comment: What is `FIP` and `BP`?

Comment: @hims056 first innings points and bonus points.

Comment: As @hims056 has indicated, there is no universal rule to decide which team qualifies. Each tournament has its own rules. Therefore this question cannot be answered without knowing what the rules are of this tournament. If this is a tournament that you have organised, then you can decide what rules to apply (e.g. most FIP points; most FP points; toss of a coin; etc.). Ideally, though, this should have been done before the tournament starts, to avoid complaints.

Comment: @Spinner, let me rephrase the question then. Generally speaking, *in most cases* aka *example with the most precedents* who would be second and who would be third?

Comment: @user1672694 First, welcome to Sports SE! Happy to have you. Second, let's keep it cordial. Our users are here to help you. If there is something they don't understand, they are requesting clarification. Thus, this detail they are requesting will potentially help them answer your question.

Comment: @edmastermind29 'If there is something they don't understand, they are requesting clarification' there hasn't been any.

Comment: @user1672694 Been any what? Let us help you.

Comment: @edmastermind29 any clarification. All that has been asked is what tournament it is so that they can look it up on cricinfo and if it existed on cricinfo I would have done so by now. But it doesn't.

Comment: There are no universal rules on this. The Universe doesn't ordain how tournaments should be run, the organisers of each one need to decide on the rules for their tournament. As the organisor of this one, you'll have to make that decision. There's no objective moral philosophy out there that can give you this answer. If you haven't made the rules in advance and now find yourself in a sticky situation where your ruling will decide who goes through then simply acknowledge that and make a decision. There is no Oracle that will allow you to out-source that decision at this point.

Comment: @Bogdanovist I didn't organize it, if you take the time to read all the comment you would know that. The universe doesn't ordain what help is either, as is apparent from everything you see here. I've told you what I want, stop trying to backup the lack of answer

Answer (score 4):

The rules regarding berth in the semi-finals/finals in case of equal points are defined for particular tournament. E.g. in the [West Indies Tri-Nation Series, 2013](http://www.espncricinfo.com/tri-nation-west-indies-2013/engine/series/597920.html?view=pointstable) (Between West Indies, India and Sri Lanka) the rules regarding berth in the finals in case of equal points were as follow:

> In the event of teams finishing on equal points, the right to play in
>   the final match or series will be determined as follows:
>
> - The team with the most number of wins
> - If still equal, the team with the most number of wins over the other team(s) who are equal on points and have the same number of wins
> - If still equal, the team with the highest number of bonus points
> - If still equal, the team with the highest net run rate

So the above rules were for **that particular tournament**. Take a look at another example: In the [ICC Champions Trophy, 2013](http://www.espncricinfo.com/icc-champions-trophy-2013/engine/series/566910.html?view=pointstable) the rules for berth in semi-finals were as follow:

> In the event of teams finishing on equal points in its Group, the
>   right to play in the semi-finals will be decided in the following
>   order of priority:
>
> - The team with the more wins in the Group stage will be placed in the higher position.
> - If there are teams with equal points and equal wins in the Group stage then in such case the team with the higher net run rate in the
>     Group stage will be placed in the higher position (refer below for the
>     calculation of net run rate).
> - If still equal, the team which was the winner of the head to head match played between them will be placed in the higher position.
> - In the highly unlikely event that teams cannot be separated by the above this will be done by drawing lots.
> - If all of the matches within a Group are a no result, the top two seeded teams will progress to the semi-finals.

Since there are different rules for different tournaments we can't say which team will progress to the final in the above case. Also you can see such rules for the current tournament from [www.espncricinfo.com](http://www.espncricinfo.com/). Just go to the series page -> open Point Table. Such rules are available in the Point Table page.

E.g. [Champions League Twenty20, 2013/14](http://www.espncricinfo.com/champions-league-twenty20-2013/content/current/series/629521.html) -> [the Point Table page](http://www.espncricinfo.com/champions-league-twenty20-2013/engine/series/629521.html?view=pointstable).

Comment: You should probably avoid a wall of text just to say 'I don't know'. You would be better off using rules for first class cricket, seeing as that is the format.

Comment: @user1672694 - I didn't say *I don't know*. I said the rules for different tournaments are different. So you need to specify the tournament you are talking about. Then we can answer exact who will progress..

Comment: @user1672694 - Also why do we use the rules of first class cricket in any tournament when that tournament has it's own rules?

Comment: I'm saying if you would have been better providing examples such as sheffield shield or county championship etc as they are more relevant.

Comment: @user1672694 - Why are those tournaments more relevant? Giving specific series' example has nothing to do with my point.

Comment: The why did you provide examples in the first place?

Comment: @user1672694 - Just avoid the examples. You will get your answer even after avoiding the examples.

Comment: @user1672694 hims056 is requesting more detail about the specifics of the tournament, the series of rules, etc. you present. This will help him answer the question. Being defensive to these requests will not help you in obtaining an adequate answer.

Comment: @edmastermind29 the thing everyone has missed is that I'm asking *what the rules **should** be*

Comment: @user1672694 From what I gather, you ask who should be ranked higher (Chargers or Hawks) given equal points. The answer has been, "there is no universal rule." hims056 has provided examples of how other tournaments handle it *because* there is no universal rule. So, *what the rules **should** be* is based on what tournament and/of set of rules you are following, which seems to be generic and unspecified. Hence, the questions.

Comment: @edmastermind29 like I said before, *in most cases*, in other words, *in this situation what is usually used*. Yes he gave examples, but they were irrelevant, as I pointed out.

Comment: @user1672694 And *in most cases*, this has been applied differently to different situations. ***What is usually used** to handle equal points to determine ranking?* is your question...which may or may not have a concrete answer. Again, no need to pontificate negativity toward others...hims056 provided sources and quoted text in accordance to the [Creative Commons](http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0/us/) license to help you out.

Comment: @edmastermind29 and what did he say? The rules are what the rules are for my comp. If I knew I wouldn't be asking.

Comment: @user1672694 "I run the stats for a cricket comp" -- Who or what is the "cricket comp?" Is this what you are unclear on?

Comment: @edmastermind29 competitions aren't people

Comment: @user1672694 but there are people who organize the competition, right? Let me rephrase, **what** is the "cricket comp?" Is this what you are unclear on?

Comment: @edmastermind29 *was* a person but there isn't anything in place for such a situation. Hence why I came here. I expected to get an answer such as 'in most cases this is how it is', not someone saying 'I can't tell you because everything is different'

Comment: @user1672694 Then my advice for you is *you decide.* You request to have our users determine which set of rules have been used most often from tournament to tournament to help you with your specific situation. hims056 and spinner has stated that there are "different rules for different tournaments." hims056 has provided examples of how this case is treated for different tournaments. If *most cases* cannot be readily determined, providing differences and examples are there to help you out...not to sidestep your question.

Comment: @edmastermind29 the issue with me deciding is bias. I know what I would do personally, but I may be seen as biased and I wish to avoid it. Hence why I am asking a community in a neutral position

Comment: @user1672694 I see...bias is a different perspective you present, and is an uncomfortable situation to be in. Why not incorporate a coin toss? 50/50 chance. Thus, are you asking for **opinions** on how to handle this situation?

Comment: @edmastermind29 I'm looking for someone to say 'I say it should be done like this because x y and z did it like this'

Comment: @user1672694 Hence, your question has been closed for being "[primarily opinion-based](http://sports.stackexchange.com/help/closed-questions)."  Our users have provided facts and references to help you out, but you are requesting opinions on how to handle your specific situation. Please review the link above and our help center for more information.

Comment: @edmastermind29 no I am requesting relevant examples, not example provided to say 'look they're different so I can't answer the question'

Comment: @user1672694 That's not the kind of question that we deal with on SE sites. What you're asking for is not answerable. This is a valiant effort at an answer, but really we want specific, answerable questions. This question isn't one.

Comment: @waxeagle I'm asking for relevant examples. Not examples to backup the lack of substantial answer. This is answerable, obviously no-one wants to.

Comment: No, examples is not specific, it's not answerable (in any coherent way). You're asking a question with no *right* answer. You want a question that might have several dozen correct answers, with no qualifications on how to test said potentially correct answers. **If you want help devising a tiebreaker scheme, then give some requirements for what kind of outcome you desire.** Asking what every league ever does is silly.